# Store user data in database separately

Tags: android, database, sqlite, store, updates

What is the best practice to store user data separately from the actual app data? The user data is a statistic and it will be collected during app usage. The database must be always updated but I have to keep the user statistic untouched. Can I store for example the statistic on one table? but can I keep this table when the App will be updated?

Update:

Sorry, I think my question was misunderstood. What is the best practice to manage two kinds of Data?

1. Save all data in one database and save the User-Data in seperetly tables? or
2. Create two Databases, one for App-data and one for User-data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly of your question, but yes, you can have multiple tables in SQLite. So you can have one table for the user, call it `tblUserStatistics` and then other tables for the app, or depending on the data, the app information could be stored in preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store your statistics in one table, but it's structure depends on what you want to save. If you want to save only numbers, you can create a table with 2 columns (1st one an ID and the second one the value you want to save), and update your rows when your data changes. If you've got multiple types of data to be saved (numbers, text, dates, whatever), you must create different columns with different data types, but still, you can do it. For your other questions the answer is yes, your table will be kept after you update your app, because it gets saved in a database which doesn't get modified when the user updates the app, just make sure that when you create the new version you don't change the name of the database.